# jQuery Datepicker error - n is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery Datepicker on a form where the fields are hidden and you click on a link to edit the value.

`<a class="pickDate edit-link" id="reqSubmitDate">Thu, Feb 27, 2014</a>`

`<input type="hidden" value="Thu, Feb 27, 2014" id="reqSubmitDateinput" name="RequisitionSubmitDate" class="hasDatepicker">`

I have the datepicker initiated on the hidden input.

`$('#reqSubmitDateinput, #orderAckDateinput, #deliveryDateinput').datepicker();`

You click the link and it opens the datepicker for its matching input.

```
$('.pickDate').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var input = id + 'input';
    $('#' + input).datepicker('show');
});
```

Then it uses the defaults I've set to take the date the user picks and put set the value of the hidden input.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.slice(0, -5);
        $('#' + id).text(date);
    }
});
```

It seems to work fine on the first two but doesn't work on the last though only the IDs are different and fit the same format. I get:

`TypeError: n is undefined        jquery.....min.js (line 5)`

It seems to stop at showing the picker.

I tried moving the first two around after the one that doesn't work to see if it was an issue with how many there are and that wasn't it. I also tried moving the non-working one near the others. No luck.

jsfiddle as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGD6B/

Comment: Please post a complete code example. And when possible, also add a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: if something is undefined then i would think that one of your pickData tags, doesnt have an ID.  When there is an issue that says that you want to look at the assignments of variables.  What would make it be undefined.  Places where undefined could be are id.  undefined + "input" = "undefinedinput" for example.  The issue where this is STICKING OUT the most is:  `id.slice(0,-5);`  if ID is undefined, thats where that error would be thrown

Comment: @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/ZGD6B/

Comment: @Fallenreaper I did a console log after it when trying to figure it out and it had the first version of the ID and the 2nd with 'input' tacked on.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a bug. If I remove `type="hidden"` from the second input, it works. If I swap the inputs and do the same, it works. So there seems to be an issue with the last hidden input when there are multiple hidden input fields.

Comment: @j08691 Hey! Thanks for figuring that out!! I was so lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran into similar issues using hidden fields with jQUery. I have typically used a hack to hide the field to get jQuery to cooperate:

```
<input style="height: 0px; width:0px; border: 0px;" id="deliveryDateinput" name="DeliveryDate" value="@Model.GEP.OrderDeliveryDate" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btc2h/1/